# How to install DKMS package and put it as root!

Tags: virtualbox, root, dkms

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and it will keep on saying dkms package is already installed and I don't know how to put it into root can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you mean run it as root?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with some context - what are you trying to do? when does the message appear, exactly?

Comment: The real question is... do you know what dkms is and what it's used for? Are you trying to install some software that uses dkms? Do you know how to use `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down your problem:

1. > it will keep on saying dkms package is already installed

   Good job! That means it is already installed and can be used.
2. > I don't know how to put it into root

   To run a package with elevated permissions, start it using the `sudo` command like so:

   ```
   $ sudo dkms
   ```

   This will prompt you for you password for the root account, then run it as root.

Good luck!